# SICP Integral Procedure

Tags: scheme, sicp

In SICP section 3.5 the following procedure is given

```
(define (integral integrand initial-value dt)
  (define int
    (cons-stream 
     initial-value
     (add-streams (scale-stream integrand dt)
                  int)))
  int)
```

I understand how the procedure itself works but not how or why it finds the integral.

Comment: It's not very clear what you find unclear, but the i:th element of the stream is Si in the definition above it.

Answer (score 0):

With some pseudocode mashup, it is

```
(integral ys z dt) = int
  where
  int = 
    [ z, ...[ dt * y + i | y <- ys
                         | i <- int ]
         ]
  -- i.e. --
  int[0] = z
  int[k+1] = int[k] + ys[k]*dt

;; or,
(integral [y, ...ys] z dt) =
    [z, ...(integral ys (z+y*dt) dt)]
(integral [] z dt) =
    []
```

which is a stream of partial sums following the definition of an integral, calculating an *approximation* of the area beneath the function's curve by the rectangle rule, under the assumption that the consecutive values of the function, `ys`, are taken at evenly spaced `x` values on the X axis at `dt` distances between them, i.e. we have

```
xs[k+1] - xs[k] = dt
ys[k] = foo(xs[k])
```

for the function `foo(x)`, at any valid index `k`.

So we don't actually have the actual `x` coordinates, as we just assume they are evenly spaced in our representation of functions as streams of their `y` values.